# Отсылать местоположение в течении определенного времени

Tags: java, android, service

После определенных действий пользователя приложение получает время(может изменяться пользователем). В это время надо отсылать на сервер местоположение пользователя в течении часа.  Как такое можно реализовать правильно?

Создал `IntentService` для этих целей, но отменить его не возможно. Т.е. если пользователь изменил время и опять запустить `startService`, то будет два запроса, и оба будут отправляться на сервер.

P.S. С определением местоположения и отправкой его на сервер проблем нет. Проблема в том, что нужно в сервисе узнать, настало ли это время. Время передается в сервис и меняется иногда. Как только пользователь изменит время, его опять таки нужно передать в сервис. А прошлый удалить.

Comment: покажите код IntentSerivce где-то ошибка

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, дело не в коде. Как я понял все что находится в `onHandleIntent` уже не остановить, пока он полностью не выполнится. Т.е. если я второй раз запущу `intentService`, то будет отправляться два запроса на сервер

Comment: может [ScheduledExecutorService](https://habr.com/post/116363/) поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал с помощью `Firebase Cloud Messages` и `FirebaseJobDispatcher`. Просто сервер в определенное время передавал сообщение по токену пользователю. Дальше телефон отсылал на сервер геолокацию в течении часа.

Comment: Сам себе режиссёр :)